# Unable to dump file using SQLMap / Directory Doesn't Exist

Tags: linux, sqlmap

Update.

Using my Kali Linux, and having found a vulnerability I am unable to dump the files. It says it's

```
'[17:05:02] [INFO] table 'prabal.mailinglist'
```

dumped to CSV file 
'/root/.sqlmap/output/www.myschoolproject.com/dump/praba/mailinglist.csv'

```
[17:05:02] [INFO] fetched data logged to text files under
```

### '/root/.sqlmap/output/www.myschoolproject.com'

root@kali:/usr/share/sqlmap# cd output
bash: cd: output: No such file or directory
root@kali:/usr/share/sqlmap#

I am sorry for the poor layout, I have zero idea on how I use this editor.

Comment: Maybe someone knows at this time of posting the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Your in the wrong directory. You should be in `/root/.sqlmap/output/` instead of being in `/usr/share/sqlmap/`.

Answer (score -2):

Logged as root use `ls -a` command in terminal to see hidden directories and you will see `.sqlmap`  directory.

Then use `cd .sqlmap` command or past address `cd .sqlmap/../.../..` to proceed further.